# How to set filename dynamically for FileOutputStream in android?

Tags: java, android, file, file-io, android-sdcard

My requirements are to have the file in the format filename.extension(.png,.mp4.mp3,txt,.....etc). 
 I want to know how I can do that.

sample code line:

```
 File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(extStore + "/Get_file/filename.jpg");
```

given my above approach?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but this bit here `"/Get_file/filename.jpg"` is a String, so you can construct that String dynamically, based on some input from the user or whatever you use to determine the correct filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` returns the actual external storage directory as a `java` `File` object calling `getAbsolutePath()` on returns its absolute  path then simply concatenate the desired file name or the path to it and create a `new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Get_file/filename.jpg")` and ceck if the file exists.. if not you'll have to create one.

Use something like this.

```
String filepath = "/Get_file/filename.jpg";
File yourFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + filepath);

if(!yourFile.exists()) {
    yourFile.createNewFile();
} 
FileOutputStream oFile = new FileOutputStream(yourFile, false);
```

Comment: Hmm.. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Answer for the question :

```
File namefile= new File(newFile);
en_Name=namefile.getName();

*** //pass the file name to fileoutputstream//***

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(extStore + "/folder/"+en_name);
```

finally i got it ...

Answer (score 0):

Add timestamps after your file name, so every time file name is different.